# Add custom weights for route calculation in Valhalla routing

Tags: routing, valhalla

Have anyone managed to add custom weights to specific road segments in Valhalla which will be taken as additional factor/cost/weight when calculating route?
I struggled to find info on this topic. I found how to add traffic, elevation, eliminate roads for route calculation but how to add some additional custom cost/weight I haven't managed to find so far.
Do some command/tool exist which Valhalla provides or is there a way to add some additional field to pbf data and take those numbers into considerations when calculating routes?